# Can you adjust text weight in TextMate?

Tags: textmate

Please help me, because unless I'm losing my mind. My text in TextMate suddenly looks a lot lighter than it should.

Screenshot: http://cl.ly/5kVW

I fired up TextMate yesterday and I noticed that suddenly the text was a little hard to read. So I ran to TextMate preferences to see if I had accidentally un-bolded all text. But I can only find it on a per-theme-basis. Text looks light to me across all themes.

I even looked through the TextMate manual but I can't seem to find anything.

Am I losing my mind?

Found screenshot of what it should look like with this same theme: http://www.monokai.nl/blog/wp-content/asdev/monokaiTheme.gif

Comment: Are you using a different font?

Comment: I think Monokai uses Monaco. I haven't changed any fonts in TextMate or OS X settings.

Comment: The fonts in each screenshot look to be different sizes, which could explain the difference. Also, your anti-aliasing settings may be different.

Comment: Hmm. Which one appears bigger to you? The size doesn't appear like it's changed. I just used the TextMate Font > Bigger / Smaller menu items, and neither direction made it look closer to what I remember. I just checked and the theme & all others are set to Monaco 12pt. I toggled the anti-aliasing feature in TextMate and turning it off makes the text look even lighter!

Comment: The one on the blog appears a bit smaller. But it could also be due to your system-wide anti-aliasing settings, differences in screen resolution, etc.

Comment: Is LCD Font Smoothing and anti-aliasing the same thing? I downloaded Secrets.prefpane and found that setting and changed it from "Best for CRT" to "Stronger" but I haven't noticed a difference.

Comment: Tested with Monaco 12, it looks just like in your screenshot. I don't recall ever seeing a jumbled mess like on the monokai screenshot on the Mac. I think the font size is 11pt in the Monokai screenshot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been seeing the same thing lately. <strike>I haven't been able to determine the cause or reliably reproduce the bug, but perhaps it is related to the most recent update (I'm using the "cutting-edge" build 1631).  I believe I began seeing the issue after the update (mid-March).</strike>

Sometimes restarting TextMate has fixed it. Sometimes I cleared the font cache, too.

As Allan noted in the [ticket I filed](http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=E7D899B2), this is due to a bug in OS 10.6 with third-party external LCD panels:

> In that case the problem is likely with the automatic selection of font smoothing (based on display), see http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090828224632809 for more details and potential workaround.

The reason restarting TextMate sometimes worked for me (and you, apparently), is because we restarted it without the external monitor attached. Running the defaults command in that Mac OS X Hints article fixes it properly.

```
defaults -currentHost write -globalDomain AppleFontSmoothing -int 2
```

Comment: Hunh. Now mine has corrupted itself once again. And neither of these solutions is working to restore it. I'm at a loss...

Comment: I've submitted a ticket at macromates.com (http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=E7D899B2). As a temporary work around, choosing the bold variant in the bugged state seems to make things look like normal. But, once TextMate magically reverts to the normal rendering, the font looks extra-bold and you must change back to the normal variant.

Comment: I just upgraded to Lion (OS X 10.7). Note that as part of the update process, this default was unset. Fortunately, this command still works on Lion. I simply had to run the command again and all was well.

Comment: this solved my problem, didn't even know it could be lcd problem

Answer (score 2):

Textmate disables Apple's particular flavor of font-smoothing [with dark themes running on retina displays](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings#controlling-font-smoothing). If you want to opt-in to the Apple version, change Textmate's settings in the terminal with:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview fontSmoothing 1
```